# my query in codeigniter cannot produce result

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've been debbuging it many times based on my knowledge, i am new to codeigniter, any solution idea would be much appreciated... ty

here's my code

MODEL:

```
function userdisplay_info($id){

        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE         userIdentificationNumber LIKE '$id'");                                 
      //if($result->num_rows() > 0){

        $info_data = $result->result();

        $row = $info_data[0];


        $result->free_result();
     }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function r_book(){

    $data = array();
    $bid = $this->input->post('bid');
    $u_id = $this->input->post('userinputid');

    $data = array(

        'book_reserved' => 1

        );

    if($this->module2->reserved_book($bid,$data))
        {



            $data['info'] = $this->module2->userdisplay_info($u_id);

            $this->load->view('User/template/header');
            $this->load->view('User/template/navigator');
            $this->load->view('User/landingpage',$data);
            $this->load->view('User/template/footer');
            return true;
        }else
            {
                $this->load->view('User/template/header');
                $this->load->view('User/template/navigator');
                $this->load->view('User/landingpagefail');
                $this->load->view('User/template/footer');
                return false;   
            }

    }
```

VIEW:

```
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <?php if($info) : foreach($info as $u_info) : ?>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Last Name : <?php echo $u_info->uid; ?></li>
                        <li>First Name : <?php echo $u_info->userFirstname; ?></li></li>
                        <li>Middle Name : <?php echo $u_info->userMiddlename; ?></li></li>
                        <li>Course : <?php echo $u_info->userCourse; ?></li></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else :?>
                <h4> No Record Found</h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What you were getting within your `$u_id` show what its printing using `print_r($u_id)`

Comment: it does not showing either in print_r, i wonder whats the problem

Comment: Then you are not getting id bro.. you need to identify that problem first

Comment: so how im gonna fix the bug? how can i retrieved the id? the above code i already modify it to simpliest way...

Comment: From where you getting `$this->input->post('userinputid');` this value just check that file, are you getting that it within that `textbox` or somewhere else

Comment: yes input textbox and i hid the type

Comment: actually the code i used to output the user's id in the textbox is similarly with this code i have been debugging, i wonder why its not working? the reason i want to output the info is i am going to use it as my refference in doing some query with the particular user..

Comment: my modify code pls dig it if u have find something $usersID = $this->input->post('userinfo')-                $data['temp'] = $this->module2->userdisplay_info($usersID);-Load->view('someview',$data)>control.                                                                                                     -                                                                                                                                  $result = $this->db->select('uid')->where('userIdentificationNumber',$uid)->from('user')->get();                                     -return $result->result();

Comment: What I am saying to you is are you getting value of u_id within post if not then paste your html or from where you are posting the value

Comment: yes i  am getting the value..

Comment: <?php if(!empty($temp)) : ?>
<?php foreach($temp as $user) <?php $user_lname = $this->$user->userLastname; $user_fname = $this->$user->userFirstname; //print_r($user); echo "<ul>"; //echo "<li>" . $user_ID . "</li>"; echo "<li>" . $user_lname . "</li>";  echo "<li>" . $user_fname . "</li>";  echo "</ul>";  ?>  <?php endforeach; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php  echo "<h4>"; echo "No Record Return"; echo "</h4>";  ?> <?php endif; ?>

Comment: You had an error within your above comment code

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your model function as

```
function userdisplay_info($id){
    $this->db->select('uid');
    $this->db->like('userIdentificationNumber', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Please, let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: still the same no result

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/module2.php

Line Number: 40

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/module2.php

Line Number: 39

Comment: the same man any other idea??? wew this is my 2nd day debugging,, i appreciate ur help man tnx.. any idea ??? help..

Comment: @MichaelMendoza what is line 39? Can use vardump or print_r your model call in controller and what you see?

Comment: still no data when i used print_r() and varr_dump()

Comment: Rewrite your model function as 

function userdisplay_info($id){

 $this->db->select('uid');
 $this->db->like('userIdentificationNumber', $id); 
 $query = $this->db->get('user');
 return $query->result_array();
}

Comment: when i used either print_r or var_dump the result will always emptyT_T

Comment: which variable you are using to print_r ?